# Why is the API for Steam Trading Cards blank?

Tags: steam, inventory

I can get the inventory for tf2 by using appID 440 and the inventory for CS:GO by using appID 730, but when I use appID 753 for Steam inventory to view trading cards, it only shows:

```
{"total_inventory_count":0,"success":1,"rwgrsn":-2}.
```

This happens on both my profile and a friend's, despite the fact that we both have trading cards. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

example: https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198043676417/753/2?l=english&count=5000

Comment: shoutout to karel for formatting my post, thanks bby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nevermind, turns out the url is https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198043676417/753/6.

Somehow changing that 2 to a 6 allows us to see the trading cards

Answer (score 0):

Its formatted https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/steamID/appID/contextID

Steam trading cards have context id 6 while csgo skins have context id 2

see [this helpfull guide](https://dev.doctormckay.com/topic/332-identifying-steam-items/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).